# VUE: Ava can't run any assertion ERROR

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, ava

My folder structure is this:

./package.json

src/Notification.js

test/notification.js

**File Notification.js**

```
export default {
  template: '<div>{{message}}</div>',
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello world'
    };
  }
};
```

**File notification.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import test from 'ava';
import Notification from '../src/Notification';
test('that it renders a notification', t => {
  new Vue(Notification).$mount();
});
```

**Error when i run: node_modules/.bin/ava**

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the 
template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
into render functions, or use the compiler-incluided build. (found in
<Root>)
1failed
that it renders a notification
test finished without running any assertions
```

If someone can say me what's wrong and explain the code, i will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your test did not use any [assertions](https://github.com/avajs/ava#assertions). You probably want to assert something on the `new Vue(Notification).$mount()` return value. If you're just making sure it doesn't throw an exception you could do `t.notThrows(() => new Vue(Notification).$mount())`.

Answer (score 0):

Vue ships with several versions, some with the template compiler and some without. The way you are importing Vue now, the template compiler is not included, so Vue cannot compile

```
template: '<div>{{message}}</div>',
```

Try instead importing a version of Vue with the compiler.

```
import Vue from "vue/dist/vue"
```

Comment: First of all, thanks Bert. Now i have other error. I put the link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097009/vue-ava-test-failed-document-is-not-defined